# How would i efficiently read a text document with the syntax of an array into an actual array?

Tags: python, arrays

So I'm reading in a text file, which was produced by simply writing the contents of an array into a file without taking any spacing into account. I want to read in the contents of the file, but place them right back into an array. My consideration is that all characters are now in String format. How would I go about if I wanted this to run efficiently on a very large document (40GB+).

These are the contents of the document:

```
[['This', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'array', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.']]
```

Comment: string array and sentence do not differ. you lost all distinctive features, so you cant.

Comment: You should focus on fixing how the text file is created. Why not use the JSON format?

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval` on the same monster PC that created that in the first place.

Comment: Fix the creation process. And do not produce 40GB files.

Comment: In theory, it should be possible to parse the file in chunks and re-write the contents as a collection of smaller files. To do this, you will need to have precise knowledge of the structure of the file. The example input shown in the question suggests the file contains a single huge list containing only lists of strings. If so, it should be fairly straightforward to parse it incrementally.

Comment: How will you or anyone else be able to tell what the correct format is? A simple string format often loses the information needed to get the original format back.